# How to autocopy data from one sheet to another?

Tags: google-sheets

I have two sheets.

How to copy all data in column to another sheet column. Automically, when I pass data to column in thw first sheet it appears in the second sheet. So, without copy/paste.

Comment: Use query formula will do.

Answer (score 0):

This will copy Col A in Sheet1 (enter the formula in row 1):

```
={Sheet1!A:A}
```

Or multiple columns:

```
={Sheet1!A:F}
```